# Dynamic soql not covering inside of the test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, sales-cloud

```apex
public class Margin {
    @AuraEnabled
            public static Map<string,string > Pricejson{get;set;}
            public static List <Order_item__c> finalPOList{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<orderitems> getPODetail(string AccId, string CustPO, Date StartDate, Date EndDate) {
         List<orderitems> orderlist = new  List<orderitems>();
        
       Pricejson = new Map<string,string>();        
       system.debug(AccId);
       system.debug(CustPO);
       system.debug(StartDate);
       system.debug(EndDate);

      String searchKey = AccId + '%'; 
      String searchKey1 = CustPO + '%'; 
      Date searchKey2 = StartDate; 
      Date searchKey3 = EndDate ; 
      system.debug('Come Data'+searchKey);
      List <Order_item__c> returnPOList = new List <Order_item__c > ();
      finalPOList = new List <Order_item__c > ();
       

     String operator1='Like';
     String operator2='=';
     String operator3='>=';
     string operator4='<=';
     
     string query = 'Select Order__r.Customer_Po__c,Order__r.Account__r.Name ,Order__r.Date_Of_Order__c,Name, Quantity__c,Total__c,Harness_Internal_Cost__c, Family__c from Order_item__c';
     String[] filters = new String[0];  
     
     if(String.isnotblank(AccId)) {
        filters.add('Order__r.Account__r.Name ' + operator1 + ' : searchKey');
      }
     if(String.isnotblank(CustPO)) {
        filters.add(' Order__r.Customer_Po__c ' + operator2 + ' : searchKey1');
      }
          if(StartDate!=NULL) {
        filters.add(' Order__r.Date_Of_Order__c ' + operator3 + ' : searchKey2');
      }
          if(EndDate!=NULL) {
        filters.add(' Order__r.Date_Of_Order__c ' + operator4 + ' : searchKey3');
      }
     
      if(filters.Size()>0) { 
         query += ' WHERE '+string.join(filters,' AND ');
      }
        query+=' LIMIT 49999 ';
     System.debug(query);
     returnPOList = database.query(query);
     System.debug('size of return list----'+returnPOList.size());
  
         system.debug('Empty');
         finalPOList.addall(returnPOList);
        
        
        
        if(finalPOList.size()>0){
        for(Order_item__c i:finalPOList){
                      

            string p='';
            string famil ='';            
            if(i.Family__c ==   'CMM - SPECIFIC_61'|| i.Family__c ==    'CMM - 100_48' || i.Family__c ==    'CMM - 200_49' ||i.Family__c == 'CMM - 300_50' ||i.Family__c == 'CMM - 220_51' ||i.Family__c ==     'CMM - 320_52' ||i.Family__c == 'CMM - 340_53' ||i.Family__c ==     'CMM backshell' ||i.Family__c ==    'CMM - 100_48_Cable assembly' ||i.Family__c ==  'CMM - 200_49_Cable assembly' ||i.Family__c ==      'CMM - 220_51_Cable assembly' ||i.Family__c ==  'CMM - 100_48' ||i.Family__c ==         'CMM - 320_52_Cable assembly' ||i.Family__c ==      'CMM - 340_53_Cable assembly' ||i.Family__c ==      'CMM - 200 BackPotting' ||i.Family__c ==        'CMM - 220 BackPotting'||i.Family__c == '   CMM PRO CABLING_555'|| i.Family__c == 'CMM PRO 200_495'|| i.Family__c == 'CMM - Common Components _54'|| i.Family__c == 'CMM PRO COMMON COMPONENTS_545'|| i.Family__c == 'CMM - CABLING_55'|| i.Family__c == '  CMM_LF CONTACT'|| i.Family__c == '  CMM - RAW MATERIALS _60'||i.Family__c == 'CMM - PARTS IN STORAGE_62'|| i.Family__c == ' CMM - MACHINES_64'|| i.Family__c == 'CMM - PACKAGING_65'){
                  famil= 'CMM';
                 }
                else if( i.Family__c == 'DMM 100_4612'|| i.Family__c == 'DMM 220_4613'|| i.Family__c == 'DMM 320_4614'|| i.Family__c == 'DMM 340_4615'|| i.Family__c == 'DMM 420_4616'|| i.Family__c == 'DMM 430_4617'|| i.Family__c == 'DFMM 220'|| i.Family__c == 'DMM 100_4612_Cable assembly'|| i.Family__c == 'DMM 220_4613_Cable assembly'|| i.Family__c == ' DFMM 220_Cable assembly'|| i.Family__c == 'DMM 320_4614_Cable assembly'|| i.Family__c == 'DMM 420_4616_Cable assembly'|| i.Family__c == '   DMM 430_4617_Cable assembly'|| i.Family__c == ' DMM backshell'|| i.Family__c == '   DMM Components_4601'|| i.Family__c == 'DMM Documentation_4602'|| i.Family__c == 'DMM Accessories_4603'|| i.Family__c == 'DMM Specific_4610'|| i.Family__c == 'DMM Cabling_4611'){
                 famil = 'DMM';
                }
             
      
        string idcom ='';
        string partno=i.Name; 
            
             system.debug('family'+famil);
             system.debug('id'+idcom);
             system.debug('partno'+partno);
            // system.debug('qunaity'+quantity);
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('website'); 
        req.setMethod('GET');
       
        String username = 'example username';
        String password = 'example password';
  
        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
        String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' +
        EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
        req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
        System.debug(req);
        Http http = new Http();
        try{   
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        System.debug(res.getbody());  
           p = res.getbody();
                
        }catch(Exception e){
         system.debug(e);
        } 
            system.debug('this is p'+p);
            system.debug('this is i'+i);
            
            Pricejson.put(i.Name,p);
            system.debug('pricejson='+Pricejson);
            
          orderitems ord =new orderitems();
          ord.OrderItems =  i;
          ord.PricingJson = Pricejson.get(i.Name);
          orderlist.add(ord);
        }
       }
     System.debug('result'+returnPOList);
     System.debug('result size'+returnPOList.size());
     System.debug('finalreturnList'+finalPOList);
     System.debug('finalreturnList size'+finalPOList.size());
     System.debug('orderlist'+orderlist);
   
    return orderlist;
 }
     public class orderitems{
           @AuraEnabled 
           public Order_item__c OrderItems;  
           @AuraEnabled 
           public string PricingJson; 
                    
    }
```

}[image]

Comment: are you creating test data for `Order_item__c` object in your test methods? If so, make sure they meet the filter criteria from your SOQL query. Also, would it be helpful if you share what `System.debug(query);` is returning on the logs

Comment: Yes i created the test data for Order_item__c object also but it not covered the main class

Comment: could you please update your post with the output returned by `System.debug(query)` and also with the code for your test class?